# How to find the type of a LogOn account in Win32 Services?

Tags: service, account, winlogon

In the Services.exe, For each service, we can see two types of LogOn

1. Local System account
2. This account.

[image: Service LogOn Property]

I am just wondering is there any way to classify the LogOn accounts in "This account" to a particular set of enum or groups.

For eg:

1. ./SomeUsername as Local User Account,
2. NT Authority/LocalService as localService
3. NT Authority/NetworkService as Network Service
   and so on.

Please give me some insights on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can look into services registry branch
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<your sevice name>`.

The value `ObjectName` is what you are looking for.

It will be text string like

- `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`
- `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`
- `LocalSystem`

in case of build-in credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the info!. In my case, I could find the startup Type but in our application, when a user chooses a particular category for eg. `LocalService` it should return all services which have the startup type as `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`. So I need to classify the startup types into various categories. But in the registry, it is returned as a string, not an enum. That's why I am wondering is there any option to classify the startup types based on the name?

Comment: You are misplacing `startup type` and `logon account`. These are a separate parameters practically with no restriction to combine with each other.

Comment: Oops! my bad. Sorry. I meant logon accounts classification only.